# Need scroll bar position or visible record info access 2010 continuous form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

The question is given at the end. Before it comes after some details about what I tried.

EDIT: I guess in technical terms I am looking for the scrollbar thumb position.

Some background on my issue:
I have created an access database to store/track issue data at an engineering firm where I work, each issue has 15 or so data fields and a picture.
Because of the frequency of out-of-office use (data is stored on network server, db is local to each user) the pictures are not embedded in each record due to the immense size of the resulting database, instead they are stored on the server with the db tables and each record contains location info so that when selected, each record dynamically embeds the pics from their stored location. The reason for this of course is to reduce db size and speed up loading from remote locations.

getting to the point...

So moving on, yesterday we had a review of what I've come up with so far, and several of the future users want me to include a continuous form that they would be able to scroll through to quickly identify a specific issue by the picture, which would be displayed on each recurrence of the form for the continuous form. Well, that sort of defeats the purpose and all of the effort I've gone through to make this database not painfully slow to use. If I did exactly as asked, access would have to insert the picture for every issue every time the form loads and that could be painfully slow.

The actual question...

My first thoughts on their request were: what if I somehow made it so that access would only run the code to insert the picture when the picture is scrolled to/over.

My logic was: although if the user scrolls through all records it will still have to load all of the pictures, I could write in the code to make it wait x seconds or something along those lines, aside from the point, either way it would stretch out the time spent loading so that it would be less noticeable to the user, right?

MY ACTUAL QUESTION!!!

So is there a way to know, for a continuous form, what the scrollbar position is?
I have searched far and wide on the internet for a working solution, but found nothing.

Comment: Have you considered thumbnails?

Comment: Yes, see the problem is as of right now it would be impossible for me to control which image format each user uses, they would all be terribly confused if I said "stick to this format it uses smaller file sizes" and It just makes for having the program have to move too much data too often

Comment: Have you considered creating thumbnails from the images in code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42708/Resize-images-using-the-Windows-Script-Host?