# Access 2007 VBA: how to get / change the current record's position on the screen

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 form that displays 40 rows. When I open it, I would like the current record's row to be displayed at row position #5, out of the 40 rows displayed. In other words, there should be 4 rows above the current row, and 35 rows below it.

*MoveUpDown* is my first cut at doing this, but currently it only works if the current record's row (as moved to by *FindFirst*) is initially displayed at row positions #1 through #5. How do I find what the current row's displayed position is, relative to the displayed rows, and how do I change it? Thanks.

```
Private Sub OpenMyFormTo(sqlWhere As String)
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, frm As Form
    DoCmd.Openform "myForm", acNormal
    Set frm = Forms("myForm").Form
    Set rs = frm.RecordsetClone
    If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        rs.FindFirst sqlWhere
        frm.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
        MoveUpDown frm.Recordset, 5
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MoveUpDown(rs As DAO.Recordset, RowsToMove As Integer)
    Dim RowsActuallyMoved As Integer, i As Integer
    RowsActuallyMoved = 0
    For i = 1 To RowsToMove
        If Not rs.BOF Then
            rs.MovePrevious
            RowsActuallyMoved = RowsActuallyMoved + 1
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 1 To RowsActuallyMoved
        If Not rs.EOF Then rs.MoveNext
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure if this is all you need:
a) to go directly to the the 5th record, use:
`DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Me.Name, acGoTo, 5`
(Me.Name only if the code is in the form's own code module)
b) you can query the current position with
`Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition`
Oddly, .AbsolutePosition starts to count at 0, the goto-command at 1.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I am asking about. `AbsolutePosition` gives me the position of the current record in the recordset, but what I want to know is the current record's row position in the rows that are being displayed on screen. 

If I have a form that is 10 rows high, then I might be displaying records that have `AbsolutePosition` values of 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, and 13. In that case, I would want to know that the record with `AbsolutePosition = 4` is in row #1, `AbsolutePosition = 5` is in row #2, etc.

Comment: I see, you need the, so to speak, display index or scroll bar position of the continuous form, _and_ the current offset from that. I would say that this is not accessible by any standard methods. No answers here in a similar question either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729786/need-scroll-bar-position-or-visible-record-info-access-2010-continuous-form

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have an answer, although it seems clunky to me. This procedure finds the target row, scrolls down until the target row is not visible, scrolls back up to the target row, overshoots the target by (Offset) additional rows, then scrolls back down to the target row. The result is that the target row is displayed as the (Offset + 1)th visible row. If the number of rows < Offset, then it is displayed as the last row.

```
Private Sub DisplayWithOffset(frm As Form, sqlWhere as String, Offset As Integer)

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, DetailsHt As Long, RowHt As Long, i As Integer
    Dim RowsVisible As Integer, BookmarkAP As Integer, RowsMoved As Integer

    DetailsHt = frm.InsideHeight _
              - frm.Section(acHeader).Height - frm.Section(acFooter).Height
    RowHt = frm.Section(acDetail).Height
    RowsVisible = IIf(RowHt > 0, DetailsHt Mod RowHt, 0)
    Set rs = frm.Recordset

    If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then

        rs.MoveLast
        rs.FindFirst sqlWhere

        BookmarkAP = rs.AbsolutePosition

        RowsMoved = 0
        For i = 1 To RowsVisible
            If rs.AbsolutePosition + 1 < rs.RecordCount Then
                rs.MoveNext
                RowsMoved = RowsMoved + 1
            End If
        Next i

        Do Until rs.AbsolutePosition = BookmarkAP
            rs.MovePrevious
        Loop

        RowsMoved = 0
        For i = 1 To Offset
            If rs.AbsolutePosition > 0 Then
                rs.MovePrevious
                RowsMoved = RowsMoved + 1
            End If
        Next i

        For i = 1 To RowsMoved
            rs.MoveNext
        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```